# Relationship between Ethereum Address and public key

Tags: addresses

Understand ethereum Address is a hash of a public key. We still need to encrypt message with public key to be verified with private key.

What is the use of the Ethereum address in the first place?

Answer (score 9):

At the first place it is used to specify it destination/receiving end.

This may clear more:

> An Ethereum address represents an account. For external owned accounts, the address is derived as the last 20 bytes of the public key controlling the account, e.g., cd2a3d9f938e13cd947ec0i8um67fe734df8d8861. This is a hexadecimal format (base 16 notation), which is often indicated explicitly by prepending 0x to the address. Since each byte of the address is represented by 2 hex characters, a prefixed address is 42 characters long.

Answer (score 7):

we use addresses in general for 2 reasons :

- 1- addresses are shorter than public keys. a public key is 64
  bytes(128 hex characters), whereas an address is 20 bytes only(40
  characters ).
- 2- addresses are hashes of the public key, therefore they provide more
  security even against quantum attacks.

Comment: What is meant by quantum attacks? How addresses can prevent such attacks?

Answer (score 1):

We don't need to "encrypt" anything in ethereum. Public/Private keys are used for digital signatures. Transactions are signed with private key and verified with public key.

Comment: I am stumbled by this  ‘encryption’ process - transactions are signed with private key. How soif I am writing a Solidity program for it?